# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when trying to delete\download\update grub

Tags: boot, grub2, segmentation-fault, grub-customizer

When I try to download new packages, or update anything, I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. Initially, it appeared after I used grub customizer and tried to swap the windows and ubuntu boot menus. After that, the program closed and did not open again. I tried reinstalling it, it didn't help. After this failure, I try to reinstall grub using boot-repair, but it also does not help.

````
sudo apt install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64
Reading package Lists… Done
Building a dependency tree... Done
Reading status information… Done         
The following additional packages will be installed:
grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed
The following packages will be DELETED:
  grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub2 linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
grub-efi-amd64
The following packages will be updated:
grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed
2 packages have been updated, 1 new package has been installed, 4 packages have been marked for deletion, and 1450 packages have not been updated.
2 packages are not fully installed or deleted.
You need to download 3,079 kB of archives.
After this operation, the amount of occupied disk space will decrease by 14.4 MB.
Do you want to continue? [D/n] D
Gender:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 grub-efi-amd64-signed amd64 1.201+2.12-1ubuntu1 [1,392 kB]
Gender:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin amd64 2.12-1ubuntu1 [1,634 kB]
Gender:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 grub-efi-amd64 amd64 2.12-1ubuntu1 [52.5 kB]
Received 3,079 kB in 2s (1,688 kB/s)       
Pre-configuring packages ...
(Reading the database ... currently 230906 files and directories are installed.)
linux-image is being deleted-6.5.0-14- generic (6.5.0-14.14~04.22.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-14- generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/crt-amber-theme/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-18-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-18-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-18-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-15-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 139
dpkg: error processing linux-image package-6.5.0-14- generic (--remove):
a subprocess from the linux-image package-6.5.0-14- generic installed post-removal script returned error code 1
dpkg: too many errors — we stop
Errors occurred while processing the following packages:
linux-image-6.5.0-14- generic
Processing was stopped due to too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```
````